# Jquery Ajax Error Callback Function

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to send data to a server to insert into a database. I am using ajax to send the data and everything is working fine until the server tries to respond. I am getting a parsererror in the console and this error:
        `Error: jQuery111107585765416733921_1428006987473 was not called {stack: (...), message: "jQuery111107585765416733921_1428006987473 was not called"}`

Here is the ajax call we are using:

```
var data = {
        action: 'newUser',
        id:id,
        value:value 
    }
    $.ajax({
        url:"http://fake.url.com",
        async:false,
        crossDomain:true,
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        data:data,
        // Work with the response
        success: function( response ) {
            console.log( response ); // server response

            if(response == 'invalid'){
                $('#takenUserName').html('<span style="color:red">Username already Exists</span>');
            }

        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error){
            console.log(xhr);
            console.log(status);
            console.log(error);
        }

    }); `
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How is the server handling this request? The method is JSONP, so it seems that you are not handling it appropriately.

Comment: most likely cross domain errors. this `crossDomain:true,` doesnt really do anything from my experience

Answer (score 0):

if you are using jsonp you have to return the value of the callback parameter in the response, otherwise it won't work,, if you want to avoid that, use the type "json" instead of "jsonp"

this is a proof to show that your client side is fine, and your server side isn't handling the response as a jsonp but maybe as a json (return the token in the response to make it jsonp) [[JsFiddle]](http://jsfiddle.net/CME64/3u2b04tt/)

```
var data = {
        action: 'newUser',
        id:'123',
        value:'val' 
    }

     $.ajax({
        url:"http://jsfiddle.net/echo/jsonp/",
        async:false,
        crossDomain:true,
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        data:data,
        // Work with the response
        success: function( response ) {
            console.log( response ); // server response

            if(response == 'invalid'){
                $('#takenUserName').html('<span style="color:red">Username already Exists</span>');
            }

        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error){
            console.log(xhr);
            console.log(status);
            console.log(error);
        }

    });
```

**[update]**

your response should look like this on the server side:

```
$_GET['callback'].'({"response":"json_object"})';
```

Comment: Here is my server side code. `if(array_key_exists('action',$_GET)
 && $_GET['action'] == 'newUser'){
  echo 'invalid';     $jsonp_callback = isset($_GET['callback']) ? $_GET['callback'] : null;

print $jsonp_callback ? "$jsonp_callback({$json})" : $json;`Can you tell me how to send it back as jsonp instead of json?

Comment: @TannerDixon sorry for the late reply. you just have to extract the "callback" token and keep it and prepare your response as a json and then insert it to your callback value inside brackets like this: callback_token(your_json_Object) i.e. `1234567890({"result":{"x":1}})` and send it back as a string response .. this worked for me 2 years ago .. tell me if it worked for you too so I can update the answer for everyone to see

Comment: I am not sure to what you are referring to. Could you help me understand where my issue is?

Comment: @TannerDixon your response should look like this on the server side `$_GET['callback'].'({"response":"json_object"})';`

Comment: Thanks for the help, I found my issue. I was trying to use echo for my response instead of using json_encode.

Comment: Your solution is correct, but our main problem was something else.